# Why won't this 555 timer flashing circuit work?

Tags: integrated-circuit, 555

The circuit which I made shows the following behavior, when power is given to the circuit:

- Sometimes it lights up, sometimes it doesn't.
- When it does light up, it flashes properly for a few seconds but then becomes dimmer and dimmer.

What is causing this unpredictable behavior? Is it the components? Or is it the breadboard?

**This is my first project using an IC**

Yellow wire shorts 4 and 8. Orange wire shorts 2 and 6

### ***UPDATE: The circuit is now working. All I had to do was change the battery!***

Circuit diagram from a YouTube video where I got the circuit:

[image: Circuit diagram from a YouTube video where I got the circuit]

---

555 pins 1, 2, 3 and 4:

[image: 555 pins 1, 2, 3 and 4]

---

555 pins 5, 6, 7 and 8:

[image: 555 pins 5, 6, 7 and 8]

Comment: What's the quality of the battery?

Comment: Lovely heart jumper +1. can you measure Voltage on each pin starting with power when Ok

Comment: Does 220 get pretty hot?  change that , what is Pd?  T> 125'C

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 What is 220? What is Pd? I dont think there is a temperature issue here

Comment: I meant 270 (Ohms)   (12V-2.1V)^2/270  = Power dissipation Pd . Record volts and be aware of heat rise

Comment: Reduce Vbat to 5V ,  change 270R to 1k

Comment: You said "Yellow wire shorts 1 and 8', presumably you meant 4 and 8

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 What is Vbat?

Comment: Battery voltage.  You ought to take measurements in future and calculate power dissipation and sense heat with finger. Vbat = = battery voltage,  batteries are like precharged supercaps with mAh capacity Ic * dt = C * dV that operate down to -10% or more until series Rs rises sharply and charge is depleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks okay to me. Try a fresh battery (almost 100% sure that’s your immediate issue), and increase the series resistor to the LED to draw less current (try 2K or so), at least temporarily. I also can’t see the color code clearly on the existing part.

You seem to have two 1uF caps, put the remaining one across the battery, observing polarity, of course.

The ancient bipolar 555s draw a large pulse of current when switching, so a bypass cap is desirable.

Comment: Im using only one 1uF capacitor

Comment: There is an orange one in the top photo and a blue one in the below photo, so did it change color between photos?

Comment: Oh, the top photo is from a YouTube video from where I got the circuit. The blue one is the one which Im using

Comment: Thanks a lot sir! I took a new battery and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Examine your specs

Battery 5~12V  and LED = Red is  20mA rated @ 2.1V,

Vbat Pd (Pd=V(^/270R)

This is OK for 5V but not 12V

Voltage across R ~ 10V for Vbat=12V  Pd=10^2/270= 370 mW for a 1/4 W resistor with 125'C rise at 1/4W. **You ought to limit temp rise to 60'C and thus only use 50% of power rating.**

Also with 10V/270R=I= 37 mA, you have not only **exceeded 20mA rating** but absolute maximum 30mA rating and are heating  up diode molecules and melting epoxy (slightly) .Can you smell it?  Epoxy fumes are toxic.

**Change 270R to 1k** and live with less bright LED or get an LED that has more efficient Luminous Intensity @ 10mA e.g. 10,000 mcd @ 20mA

Answer (score 0):

Measure voltage between pins 1 & 8 (right at the pins) to make sure it stays constant at battery voltage level. If it droops then bad connection between battery and I.C.

Measure voltage at pin 3. See if 'pulse high' level stays at constant amplitude or reduces over several pulses. If it stays constant or rises then bad connection between pin 3 & ground (via LED).